# C# - Xamarin.iOs - Add a nonce to xamarin.auth request

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I don't find a way to add a nonce to my Xamarin.Auth request to connect to my okta login. I'm kind of new to xamarin and nugets package and i don't know how to modify the implementation of OAuth2Authenticator of the version 1.3.0.

I'm trying to use request parameter as :

> auth.RequestParameters.Add("nonce", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));

but i keep running in the nonce invalid error from okta.

If any of you has an idea how to fix it.

Here comes the full request:

```
   //start login flow seting our openId flow
    public void StartFlow(string responseType, string scope)
    {

        //webViewLogin.Hidden = false;
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId: OAuthClientId,
            scope: scope,
            authorizeUrl: new Uri(oktaTenantUrl),
            redirectUrl: new Uri(OAuthRedirectUrl)
            );
        auth.RequestParameters.Add("nonce", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
        auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            DismissViewController(true, null);
            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                    // Use eventArgs.Account to do wonderful things
                }
        };
        PresentViewController(auth.GetUI(), true, null);
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I get this error from server
> The+authentication+request+has+an+invalid+nonce+parameter.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simpler way to achieve this. It seems this is a bug/not well documented process. This [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/134) explains what to do:

> You could probably override OnCreatingInitialUrl:
>   https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/ad7f6d6453506ced0ab3af499a7492f13973e3a3/source/Xamarin.Auth.LinkSource/OAuth2Authenticator.cs#L322
>
> The RequestParameters property doesn't look to be used from what I can
>   see, or at least not in that version.

So the solution would be to make another class that inherits `OAuth2Authenticator` and override the OnCreatingInitialUrl:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Auth;

namespace Alerte.Health.App.Droid.Classes
{
    public class MyOAuth2Authenticator : OAuth2Authenticator
    {
        public MyOAuth2Authenticator(string clientId, string scope, Uri authorizeUrl, Uri redirectUrl, GetUsernameAsyncFunc getUsernameAsync = null, bool isUsingNativeUI = false) : base(clientId, scope, authorizeUrl, redirectUrl, getUsernameAsync, isUsingNativeUI)
        {
        }

        public MyOAuth2Authenticator(string clientId, string clientSecret, string scope, Uri authorizeUrl, Uri redirectUrl, Uri accessTokenUrl, GetUsernameAsyncFunc getUsernameAsync = null, bool isUsingNativeUI = false) : base(clientId, clientSecret, scope, authorizeUrl, redirectUrl, accessTokenUrl, getUsernameAsync, isUsingNativeUI)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnCreatingInitialUrl(IDictionary<string, string> query)
        {
            query.Add("nonce",Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this instead of OAuth2Authenticator, and proceed with the normal process:

```
var auth = new MyOAuth2Authenticator(
    clientId,
    scope,
    new Uri(authorizeUrl),
    new Uri(redirectUrl));
```

etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Finaly got working by modifying the OAuth2Authenticator, adding a nonce to the first request.

Here is the fix:

```
public override Task<Uri> GetInitialUrlAsync()
    {
        var url = new Uri(string.Format(
            "{0}?client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&response_type={3}&scope={4}&state={5}&nonce={6}",
            authorizeUrl.AbsoluteUri,
            Uri.EscapeDataString(clientId),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(this.redirectUrl.AbsoluteUri),
            IsImplicit ? "token" : "code",
            Uri.EscapeDataString(scope),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(requestState),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(nonce)));



        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Uri>();
        tcs.SetResult(url);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

with

```
  this.nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that w/o inheriting `Authenticator` it is impossible to intercept calls in ctor and 1st HTTP request happens already in ctor.

When the code gets to:

`auth.RequestParameters.Add("nonce", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));`

Parameters are already created and HTTP request already fired.

Both answers above are fine for workarounds, but inheriting is needed.

It is planned to add another Dictionary to ctor for custom parameters, so they could be prepared on time.